# Does `load` prefer .elc files over .el files?

Tags: byte-compilation, load-path

Do `.elc` files take precedence over `.el` files when using `load`?

Say I have two files in my load path: `foo.el` and `foo.elc`. If I call `(load "foo")`, will the byte-compiled version (`foo.elc`) always be loaded instead of the uncompiled `foo.el`?

Comment: Yes. See the Emacs manual, node [Lisp Libraries](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Libraries.html). (Ask Emacs.)

Comment: See also `load-prefer-newer`, which can customize this behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default the `.elc` would be loaded rather than the `.el`, as noted in the other answers/comments.

A few things can affect this behavior, however:

- Set `load-prefer-newer` to `t` if you want to load whichever file is newer. In that case the `.el` will be loaded if it has been modified more recently than the corresponding `.elc` file.
- See the variable `load-suffixes`, which defines the suffixes that `load` will try, in order of preference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `.elc` files take precedence over `.el` files, even if they both exist in your load path.

According to [emacswiki.org](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LoadPath):

> When both a byte-compiled file (*.elc) and a source file (*.el) are found for the same library, preference is given to byte-compiled file.

Comment: The wiki is generally (and in this case) a good source. But Emacs is typically a better source, when it covers the same information.