# Can we force emacs to not load byte compiled files?

Tags: byte-compilation

I would like Emacs to not use `byte-compiled` files because the stack-trace is really messy.

So for my own `elisp` files, I can add `;; -*-no-byte-compile: t; -*-` to disallow `byte-compilation`.

But how can I enforce this for the packages like `evil` downloaded from `elpa`, `melpa` etc?

1. Can I prevent package installation from `byte-compiling` so
   that there are no `.elc`'s created in the first place?
2. If that is not possible, I could probably delete them, but would
   that not be recreated or is that automatically happening during
   the installation only?

The comment says that I can remove the `load-path` of `.elc`, but as far as I know, both `.el` and `.elc` is on the same path!

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36846/package-el-how-can-i-avoid-byte-compilation?

Comment: No, that question is about avoiding/preventing compiling. This question seems to be about not loading existing *.elc files. But it's your question! So you tell us - is that question really what you want to ask? If so, delete this one.

Comment: You can always delete byte-compiled files or move them out of your `load-path` (directly or indirectly).

Comment: This may help: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/31029

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does \`load\` prefer .elc files over .el files?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31020/does-load-prefer-elc-files-over-el-files)

Comment: @YasushiShoji: This is not a duplicate of that question either, AFAICT.

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent package installation from byte-compiling.  Write the following one liner in `~/.emacs.d/elpa/.dir-locals.el`.  This is described in [package.el: How can I avoid byte-compilation](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/36846/)

```lisp
((emacs-lisp-mode . ((no-byte-compile . t))))
```

Or you can make Emacs to only load `.el` files, no `.elc` files.  Write the following code in your `.init.el`.   This is described in [Does `load` prefer .elc files over .el files?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/31020/31029#31029)

```lisp
(setq load-suffixes '(".el"))
```

Comment: Trying to achieve the same objective (don't load any byte-compiled LISP) in a different environment with straight.el as package manager. Both `(setq load-suffixes '(".el"))` or `(setq load-suffixes '(".el" ".elc"))` in my init.el result in the following error on startup:
`Eager macro-expansion failure: (error "Recursive load" "/usr/local/share/emacs/27.2/lisp/jka-compr.el.gz" ... ) [8 times]`